# Photoshop "image processor" using files of the same name but in different folders?

Tags: photoshop, batch

I am trying to batch process around 50 files. All of the files are in the same folder, so I choose that folder for the "image processor" to run in. However, I have previously processed (in a different folder) several hundred files with the same name. Photoshop seems to be confused and will open the correct images, but then will open other images by the same name in a different folder and will save those to the batch output folder and leave the correct files open and processed, but not saved to the output folder. I've tried restarting photoshopp but that did nothing. Anyone experienced this before and is there something potentially happening in my workflow or something to cause this?

Comment: vtc b/c problem caused by user error.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I had accidentally recorded over the action I was trying to use and had it set to close the current file and then open another file, which caused this.